# GUI Javascript compiler that obfuscate / merge multiple files in one?

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, merge, obfuscation

Is there any lightweight tool that obfuscate Javascript and also merge multiple source files into one single output?

I'd really like some OSX tool that does similar as [Scout](http://mhs.github.io/scout-app/) does with SCSS. Once it started it keeps output files synced whenever a source is changed.

Comment: Have you tried looking yourself? You should have encountered [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) (and subsequently [`grunt-contrib-concat`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat)) at least once

Comment: Yap, gone with grunt. Especially like [grunt-includes](https://github.com/vanetix/grunt-includes).